# Testing whether AVX register contains some equal integer numbers

Tags: c++, x86, simd, avx, avx2

Consider a 256-bit register containing four 64-bit integers.
Is it possible in AVX/AVX2 to test efficiently whether some of these integers are equal?

E.g:

a) `{43, 17, 25, 8}`: the result must be `false` because no 2 of the 4 numbers are equal.

b) `{47, 17, 23, 17}`: the result must be 'true' because number `17` occurs 2 times in the AVX vector register.

I'd like to do this in C++, if possible, but I can drop down to assembly if necessary.

Comment: What's the threshold for "efficiently"? It can be done, but it's quite annoying

Comment: @harold, the threshold is that it must be faster than the same accomplished without SIMD (sequentially).

Comment: Incidentally this is called "Conflict Detection" and the next thing after AVX2, called AVX-512, has an extension called CDI for just this purpose. Specifically, you want `vpconflictq`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist , that's great news and I also need it for conflict detection: can't perform vector operation if some targets share array index. Instead I have to do them one after another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With **AVX512** (AVX512VL + AVX512CD), you would use [`VPCONFLICTQ`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4653,525,3,4701,4695,4602,4601,97,3289,4601,4602,97,4601,1191&text=VPCONFLICTQ), which is designed for this purpose.

---

For **AVX2**:

Shaved off a couple of operations by doing fewer redundant comparisons:

```
int test1(__m256i x)
{
    __m256i x0 = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(x, 0x4B);
    // 1 0 2 3
    // 3 2 1 0
    __m256i e0 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(x0, x);
    __m256i x1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(x, 0x4E);
    // 2 3 0 1
    // 3 2 1 0
    __m256i e1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(x1, x);
    __m256i t = _mm256_or_si256(e0, e1);
    return !_mm256_testz_si256(t, _mm256_set1_epi32(-1));
}
```

---

Previously:

A simple "compare everything with everything" approach can be used with some shuffles, something like this (not tested):

```
int hasDupe(__m256i x)
{
    __m256i x1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(x, 0x4E);
    __m256i x2 = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(x, 0x4E);
    __m256i x3 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(x2, 0x4E);
    // 2 3 0 1
    // 3 2 1 0
    __m256i e0 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(x1, x);
    // 1 0 3 2
    // 3 2 1 0
    __m256i e1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(x2, x);
    // 0 1 2 3
    // 3 2 1 0
    __m256i e2 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(x3, x);
    __m256i t0 = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_or_si256(e0, e1), e2);
    return !_mm256_testz_si256(t0, _mm256_set1_epi32(-1));
}
```

GCC 7 compiles this to reasonable code, but Clang does really strange things. It seems to think that `vpor` has no 256 bit version (which it totally does). Changing the ORs to additions does roughly the same thing in this case (adding a couple of -1's together will not be zero) and doesn't cause trouble with Clang (also not tested):

```
int hasDupe(__m256i x)
{
    __m256i x1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(x, 0x4E);
    __m256i x2 = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(x, 0x4E);
    __m256i x3 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(x2, 0x4E);
    // 2 3 0 1
    // 3 2 1 0
    __m256i e0 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(x1, x);
    // 1 0 3 2
    // 3 2 1 0
    __m256i e1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(x2, x);
    // 0 1 2 3
    // 3 2 1 0
    __m256i e2 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(x3, x);
    // "OR" results, workaround for Clang being weird
    __m256i t0 = _mm256_add_epi64(_mm256_add_epi64(e0, e1), e2);
    return !_mm256_testz_si256(t0, _mm256_set1_epi32(-1));
}
```

Comment: So it's 8 vector operations, while naive solution for pairwise comparison would require 4*3/2 = 6 comparisons... But the number of operations in the latter may be substantially more than 6 in assembly because of array offsetting. While vector operations almost map to the same in assembly, I guess. So it needs measurements.
I've moved your AVX512 solution to the top, if you don't mind.

Comment: @SergeRogatch probably a more significant difference is that the results of the comparisons have to be used/merged somehow - for example `setcc` them and `or` them all together (and then branch on it I guess?), which would add 6 `setcc`'s and either 5 or 2 `or`'s (2 if cheating with high-byte registers, so it also costs 3 extra recombination µops, no free lunch there). That about doubles the instruction count for a scalar version